# How do I restart a container with a new spring-boot JAR without absolute path to jar?

Tags: java, docker, spring-boot, jar, dockerfile

Please help me to solve my problem.

With the upgrade of the docker, adding jar to the container with the absolute path no longer works. How to make, that at restart of the container the new jar was picked up?
I did a new jar and restarted the container, now I can not do this because it's impossible to specify the absolute path to the new jar in Dockerfile?

Here is my Dockerfile that worked before updating to the new version of the docker. From him I created a image without any problems.

```
FROM java:8

VOLUME /tmp
EXPOSE 8888
ADD /home/jdev/docker-storage/jenkins/workspace/CA/build/libs/ca.jar /app.jar
RUN bash -c 'touch /app.jar'
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

Now I can not create an image, because I need to specify a relative path. And after restart a new image is not copied to the Docker-container. Dockerfile is in /home/jdev.

`ADD docker-storage/jenkins/workspace/CA/build/libs/ca.jar /app.jar`

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You should treat the Docker container as an immutable container.  When you use this approach most of the problems you are experiencing will go away.

This setup has served me fairly well recently. Not sure if you are using Maven.  This is a Maven based solution.

First create a `docker` directory within the root of your project.

Add this `Dockerfile` to the new directory (include any specific config required)

```
FROM java:8u111-jdk-alpine

COPY *.jar target/@project.artifactId@-@project.version@.jar

CMD java -Xmx512m -jar target/@project.artifactId@-@project.version@.jar
```

Configure Maven to work with the new `docker` directory and `Dockerfile`

Add the following to the `pom.xml`

```
         <resource>
            <directory>${project.basedir}/docker</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <targetPath>..</targetPath>
        </resource>
```

Now when you package your project, you will have a correct `Dockerfile` within the `target` folder.